# chrome crashes starting from cli

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, crash

I'm trying to create a script (AutoIt) to startup chrome from CLI, but not having any success. It seems to start okay the first time, but something breaks (probably caused by something in the interaction between the script and the target webpage) as then all subsequent attempts from the CLI fails to start up Chrome properly. The browser window opens, but nothing works, and I get a sad face icon on the browser tab. Opening any new tab shows the same sad face, and waving the mouse over the icon it says "crashed" - see screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The script is probably the trigger for the problem, but I don't think it is why the problem persists, as even if I try just running chrome from the CLI (ie not using any script), I get the same result.
But if I start Chrome from the GUI, it always works just fine.

It did resume working at one point, so perhaps the problem self-clears after some time - like hours or next day, but running the script again caused the problem to return. Closing chrome or even rebooting the PC doesn't clear the problem.

I can't find what/why it is different from the CLI vs GUI.
Any suggestions on what would cause this, but also, how to reset it to a working state?
Thanks for any help.

- Rod.

Details:
Windows 2019 Server (as a VirtualBox VM on Windows 10 PC).
Latest version of Chrome (v112.0.5615.87, 64bit).

Tried starting from GUI (desktop shortcut) - works okay every time.
Tried changing working directory from CLI - problem persists.
Tried changing various CLI switches for Chrome - problem persists.
Tried running "start chrome" - also fails.

And just as I type this up, I notice that having an already started Chrome window (started from the GUI), then running the CLI command successfully opens a new Chrome window - so that one is working okay.